# SetFileSecurity() Function

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using windows OS.

In my c++ application, I am creating the files,editing and reading already existing files.

My requirement is the files should be accessed only via my application. Those files should not be accessed(opening, editing, reading) by other than my application and users.

Can I meet my requirement using windows api SetFileSecurity()?

Comment: The first thing I get when I search for this function is "This function is obsolete. Use the SetNamedSecurityInfo function instead.".

Comment: You cannot do that reliably - an administrator can always take ownership.  If you want a more secure approach encrypt the contents with a key only known to your application (again, not 100% reliable)

Comment: windows security model based on user not on application. you can grant or denny access to user but not to application

Comment: The only reliable way is to protect the file using a user-supplied password (not a saved or hardcoded one), and that's assuming that noone keylogs or debugs your application at the saving time.